# The source window should remain active after dropping an item in another window

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I have two windows opened in Windows 10. Whenever I drag a file from one window to another, the window where I drop the item is active.

But I would like to keep the window from which I dragged the file from to stay active, so I can use keyboard shortcuts in the source window.

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: After the drag is complete, press alt-tab once to switch back. Only way, and will not work if you do something like a file transfer as that may create a new popup window spawned from the source, and then that window becomes blocked until the transfer is complete.